# Saving new item to UL-List via Jquery

Tags: jquery, html-lists

I have following problem: I have an UL-List and i want to add values through an input field into this list via jquery. After Clicking a save-link the input should appear as new li entry.

The html

```
<ul id="first">
<li><input name="" size="40" maxlength="60" value="" id="up-form" /> <a href="javascript:;" onClick="javascript: $('#first').add('<li>'+$('#up-form').val()+'</li>');">Save</a></li>
</ul>
```

When clicking on the Save-Link the value of the Input field does not appears as a new li in the list. Any ideas or tipps?

Answer (score 1):

You would be better of with a click event, like this:

```
$("#first > li > a").click(function(){
  $("#first").append('<li>'+$('#up-form').val()+'</li>');

  return false;
});
```

You could also use `$(this).closest("ul").append('<li>'+$('#up-form').val()+'</li>');`.

Then the HTML can be changed to:

```
<ul id="first">
  <li><input name="" size="40" maxlength="60" value="" id="up-form" /> <a href="">Save</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

change [`.add`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) to [`.append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Quote from the `add` method

> the `.add()` method constructs a new
>   **jQuery object** from the union of those
>   elements and the ones passed into the
>   method.

Quote from the `append` method

> The `.append()` method **inserts** the specified content as the
>   last child **of each element in the
>   jQuery collection**

Demo at http://www.jsfiddle.net/yS7eG/